# Number Format Exception in keyListener

Tags: java, keylistener, numberformatexception

```
weightField.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
            char c = e.getKeyChar();
            if (!((c >= '0') && (c <= '9') || (c == KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE) || (c == KeyEvent.VK_DELETE))) {
              getToolkit().beep();
              e.consume();
            }
            if(serviceTypeComboBox.getSelectedIndex() == 0 && letterTypeComboBox.getSelectedIndex() == 0){
                priceField.setText(Integer.toString((Integer.parseInt(weightField.getText())/500) * 23000));
            }else if(serviceTypeComboBox.getSelectedIndex() == 0 && letterTypeComboBox.getSelectedIndex() == 1){
                priceField.setText(Integer.toString((Integer.parseInt(weightField.getText())/500) * 40000));
            }else if(serviceTypeComboBox.getSelectedIndex() == 1 && letterTypeComboBox.getSelectedIndex() == 0){
                priceField.setText(Integer.toString((Integer.parseInt(weightField.getText())/500) * 11000));
            }else if(serviceTypeComboBox.getSelectedIndex() == 1 && letterTypeComboBox.getSelectedIndex() == 1){
                priceField.setText(Integer.toString((Integer.parseInt(weightField.getText())/500) * 25000));
            }
        }});
```

I have no idea why I receive  java.lang.NumberFormatException when I type a key...:
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""

Comment: you should add the check that weightField.getText() is not an empty string

Comment: Also care about integer division

Comment: I would replace `(c >= '0') && (c <= '9')` with `Character.isDigit(c)`, and add `else return` to the first `if`. There's also too much duplication there - try parsing `weightField.getText()` before the chain of `if`s.

Comment: I add this check and two other checks and I have not exception anymore, but now when I type a key the string will have one less key! the last key have not effect...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to your code only:

```
 weightField.getText()
```

returning an empty String can trigger the exception. Verify you get a value there. 
I also recomend you to try/catch for that exception to notify the user that seems to enter a value to a TextField.

Comment: My last problem solved, but now I have one other problem, I defined this code: `String weight; if(c == KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE || c == KeyEvent.VK_DELETE || ((c >= '0') && (c <= '9'))){
           weight = weightField.getText();
          }else{
           weight = weightField.getText() + c;
          }` so I have a new problem that when I type a key the last key will not show...

Comment: I dont fully understand your new issue. without verification i assume this method should trigger on each key pressed individually and you query the ONE key pressed with "char c = e.getKeyChar();". What do you expect from "when i type a key the last key not shown"?

Comment: I know that I can't write English well, I'm sorry because of that. My problem solved, thank you for your time and your help :)

Comment: No worries mate english is not my mothers tongue too so it could as well be a problem of the receiver ;) Glad i could help, have fun ;)

Answer (score 2):

Since you have no parenthesis your logical operation is equivalent to:

```
! (c >= '0' && 
  (c <= '9' || c == KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE || c == KeyEvent.VK_DELETE) )
```

To have a non-digit/backspace/delete that does not enter into your beep() if block, you just need to enter:

- a character whose ascii code is larger than 48 ('0') - any alphabetic character
  OR
- `c > '9' && c == KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE && c == KeyEvent.VK_DELETE)`

Since it is an OR, you just need to input an alphabetic character.

Comment: That part of code work correctly, it is about weight.getText()

Comment: Actually I found that code in this site before, I do not change it and it work correctly